# Align text in asp:Radiobuttonlist

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

The image below is the current situation of my problem.

[image]

How to make the text to stay right after the radiobutton? Below is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <asp:Label ID="AutoContra" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Font-Bold="true">Auto Contra</asp:Label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">:</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="autcon" runat="server" CssClass="radio" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1"><span style="color:red;">*</span></div>
</div>
```

Any helps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use radio button `css` style `cssclass="rbl"`

```
<style type="text/css">
   .rbl input[type="radio"]
   {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 5px;
   }
</style>
<asp:RadioButtonList   ID="autcon" runat="server" CssClass="rbl" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```